# New binding in javascript?

Tags: javascript, binding

In the below binding snippet:

```
function foo(something) {
    this.a = something;
}

var obj1 = {};

var bar = foo.bind( obj1 );
bar( 2 );
console.log( obj1.a ); // 2

var baz = new bar( 5 );
console.log( obj1.a ); // 2
console.log( baz.a ); // 5
```

In this step `var bar = foo.bind( obj1 );` we are binding `obj1` which is empty to the `foo` function .

After executing `bar(2)` , `obj1` value 2 .

Want to know what `bar(2)` had triggered?

**My Assumption:**

Since `bar` is assigned to `foo` and binded with `obj1` , invoking `bar(2)` could have assigned the `this.a = 2` and kept that value in `obj1`(i.e.obj1 = { a: 2 }).

Is my assumption right?

Answer (score 2):

Here `bind(obj1)` works like you are overriding default `scope` of `foo` `function` to `obj1` ,so `this` keyword replaced with blank object (`obj1`) inside `foo`.

```
function foo(something) {
    //this = {}  (obj1);
    //this.a == obj.a
    this.a = something;
}

var obj1 = {};

var bar = foo.bind(obj1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `bind()` on a function returns a new bound function. When you call this bound function, it will execute the original function with the context you passed in as the first argument. Therefore `this` inside `foo` points to `obj1` when you call it through the bound function.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this , You need to first take what .bind does?

bind is function which returns another function which is called bound.

```
function x (){
  console.log(this.item)
}
```

consider the above code , does not have any idea about what `item` is.

```
var obj = { item  : 10};
```

consider this object , this object does know about its item property.

When you call .bind on `x` object(the function) , it returns the same copy of function(called **bound**) , but with the context of `obj {item: 10}`.

```
var bound = x.bind(obj);
```

This particular statement says , give this particular function with the context of obj.

Now if we call `bound()` it will print `10`

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right.

```
 var bar = foo.bind( obj1 );
```

makes bar a reference to the foo object. Thus, you can now access the function via bar.

```
 bar( 12 );
```

prints 12 if you call `console.log()` and so on.